# Group Travel with Virtual Guide

Tags: tours, group-travel

I just recently returned from an Intrepid Tour to Eastern Europe.  Tour group size was about 12 people.  Trip was great, but I felt as if the value for the money wasn't ideal.

I'm wondering if there is a site or an organization that provides fully organized tours like the big tour companies, but without all the overhead.  So, meaning the ability to book the trip (for some small fee), meet and follow the tour with the fellow members of the group, but only have a virtual tour guide to help answer questions, etc.  I'd like the tour to be carefully laid out with links to each accommodation each day, (hotlink direct to the booking page), trains, buses, etc. and ability to communicate with group members through app to coordinate any activities during each day of the trip.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Comment: I'm intrigued by the concept, but this would seem to me to combine the worst of both guided and independent travel. You'd be matched with strangers and have to follow a fixed itinerary, with none of the flexibility of independent travel, but you also wouldn't have an actual guide to show you things, handle the logistics, make sure you don't get lost, etc... So people who want the convenience of a guided tour wouldn't be satisfied with this, nor would people who don't want to be stuck with a group.

Answer (score 1):

There are self guided tours in the adventure world, such as cycling or walking tours.  Routes are described, hotels booked, luggage moved, restaurants suggested, etc.  No guide but a phone number to call if you need help or have questions.  These are usually private for you & friends, not join in groups.